# jQuery Get request with current session

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, get

How can I use jQuery to get the html of another page while its signed into that web page.
To put it simply, $.get() another page of the same site and pass the PHP/Javascript cookies so that the page returned is the page that has content that is only shown when you are signed into that site.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do anything special. Basically your browser will send the session ID along with the XmlHttpRequest. So call `session_start` in your other page and generate content based on the information in `$_SESSION`.

Comment: As you can tell by my original post, this doesn't work. If it did, I wouldn't be asking how to make it work.

Comment: @John: You mean the original post where you didn't mention the code you used or even what problems you ran into? :-)

Comment: And we're saying (well, @Eric is, we just voted him up) that the reason for your problem should be somewhere else. The browser will automatically pass on any cookies, as long as they haven't expired and match the domain and path. Use the browser dev tools to inspect the headers of the response which set the cookie, of the request generated by `$.get`, and the cookie itself as present inside the browser. That might give a bit more insight into what exactly is going on. Also, the current date/time on client when the cookie was set.